# React context value becomes undefined in intervals

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

Assume I have a provider as follows:

```
const ConnectionProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [pairings, setPairings] = useState([]);

  const value = { pairings, setPairings };

  console.log('Provider render', setPairings);

  return <ConnectionContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</ConnectionContext.Provider>;
};
```

And a hook that uses the above values:

```
export const usePairings = () => {
  const { pairings, setPairings } = useContext(ConnectionContext);
  console.log('Hook render', setPairings);

  const removePairing = useCallback((id) => {
    setPairings((prevPairings) => prevPairings.filter((pairing) => pairing.id !== id));
  }, [setPairings]);

  const addPairing = useCallback((pairing) => {
    setPairings((prevPairings) => [...prevPairings, pairing]);
  }, [setPairings]);

  return { pairings, addPairing, removePairing };
};
```

When I run the application, I see in my developer tools:

```
Provider render BoundFunctionObject { … }
Hook render BoundFunctionObject { … }
Hook render BoundFunctionObject { … }
Hook render undefined
Provider render BoundFunctionObject { … }
Hook render BoundFunctionObject { … }
Hook render BoundFunctionObject { … }
Hook render undefined
Provider render BoundFunctionObject { … }
```

It appears that at some points `setPairings` is undefined in custom hook, and right after that the provider gets re-rendered.
I was expecting a re-render of hook that is caused by a re-render of provider, but not the other way around.

Why does `setPairings` become undefined in intervals?

Comment: Are you calling `usePairings` inside a component that's wrapped by `ConnectionProvider`?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar Yes.

Comment: What is the default value of the `ConnectionContext`?